# pgbouncer fails to start when configured to dockerized postgres

Tags: pgbouncer

I am trying to configuer pgbouncer for the first time.

My postgres DB is running as a container (with port 5011)

My OS is debian 10.

I used apt-install to install pgbouncer:

```
sudo apt-get install pgbouncer
```

and then could see that pgbouncer status was OK:

```
# sudo systemctl status pgbouncer
● pgbouncer.service - LSB: start pgbouncer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/pgbouncer; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-05-26 16:15:49 IDT; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/pgbouncer.service
           └─4392 /usr/sbin/pgbouncer -d /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
```

my database name is mydb, postgres container is running on port 5011, so I configured /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini like this:

```
[databases]
octopus-bouncer = host=10.1.1.1 port=5011 user=dbauser dbname=mydb

;; Configuration section
[pgbouncer]
auth_file = userlist.txt

; IP address or * which means all IPs
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432

; any, trust, plain, crypt, md5, cert, hba, pam
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt

; total number of clients that can connect
max_client_conn = 100

; default pool size.  20 is good number when transaction pooling
; is in use, in session pooling it needs to be the number of
; max clients you want to handle at any moment
default_pool_size = 20
```

I finally put my user to /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt:

```
"dbauser" "mypassword"
```

Then I restarted pgbouncer - but failed:

```
# sudo systemctl restart pgbouncer
Job for pgbouncer.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status pgbouncer.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

status shows only this:

```
# sudo systemctl status pgbouncer
● pgbouncer.service - LSB: start pgbouncer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/pgbouncer; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-05-26 17:04:00 IDT; 2min 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 28111 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/pgbouncer start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 26 17:04:00 Octopus systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start pgbouncer...
May 26 17:04:00 Octopus pgbouncer[28111]: Starting PgBouncer: pgbouncer failed!
May 26 17:04:00 Octopus systemd[1]: pgbouncer.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 26 17:04:00 Octopus systemd[1]: pgbouncer.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 17:04:00 Octopus systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start pgbouncer.
```

Am I missing something?
How can I debug the problem?

Comment: I managed to start pgbouncer by starting it from postgres user, instead of root, and by using this command: /usr/sbin/pgbouncer -d -R -v /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini . pgbouncer log shows that pgbouncer is up and running: 2021-05-27 16:38:50.475 19862 LOG process up: pgbouncer 1.9.0, libevent 2.1.8-stable (epoll), adns: c-ares 1.14.0, tls: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019.
however, when trying to log to psql from the container with psql to pgbouncer port 6432 get error: psql: ERROR:  no such database: mydb

Answer (score 1):

You can add KillSignal=SIGINT to service unit file:

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/pgbouncer.service
[Unit]
Description=A lightweight connection pooler for PostgreSQL
Documentation=man:pgbouncer(1)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes

User=postgres
Group=postgres

# Path to the init file
Environment=BOUNCERCONF=/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini

#Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug

ExecStart=/usr/bin/pgbouncer -q ${BOUNCERCONF}
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pgbouncer -R -q ${BOUNCERCONF}
KillSignal=SIGINT

# Give a reasonable amount of time for the server to start up/shut down
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

from pgbouncer man:

```
Signals
   SIGHUP Reload config.  Same as issuing the command RELOAD on the console.
   SIGINT Safe shutdown.  Same as issuing PAUSE and SHUTDOWN on the console.
```